# How to solve Out of memory error in android after using volley lib and image loader?

Tags: api, out-of-memory, android-volley, picasso, universal-image-loader

I am getting out of memory error, App crash frequently even though I used picasso,Volley lib, Universal image loader to view images.
I am using volley lib to make API call.

```
       public class Holder
      {
       TextView title,Category,Amount;
       NetworkImageView img;
      }
       @Override
         public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)           

      {
      Holder holder=new Holder();
       View rowView;
       File cacheDir;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.solvent_list_forproduct, null);
        holder.img=(NetworkImageView)     

        rowView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);

        ImageLoader imageloader =   
        ImageGetter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        holder.img.setImageUrl
        (VarproductImageList.get(position)
        .replace(" ", "%20").toString(),   imageloader);
        }
```

Some time it through Negative Array size exception.

Comment: Use Glide Image Library - http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Thank you. I think it will help me.

Comment: I used Glide lib but getting  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000023e2 (code=-6), thread 9186 (rm.android.test) on scroll of listview. and app crash. please help me.

Comment: Check your code with this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Yes I have used same code. But still i am getting out of memory error. and Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000023e2 (code=-6), thread 9186 (rm.android.test) on scroll of listview. can you connect in Team viewer?